# What's the idiom for getting lost in a (malfunctioning) bureaucracy?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In German, the noun "sand"<sup>1</sup> has a verb form, *versandet*, which is used to express how items get completely lost in the bureaucracy of administration, and even are not done at a later stage. Is there a direct English equivalent of this verb? Failing that, what's the closest idiom?

I am trying the following translation:

> - German: Die Anfrage ist im Gebtriebe der Bürokratie versandet.
> - English: The request got lost in the bowels of the administration.

But I am not happy with it because my impression is that the verb *got lost* 
expresses that something unexpected happened, whereas 
the original German meaning is that the administration
is not properly functioning. Also, I want to make it clear that the problem is not with the request - it's not getting lost because it's too complicated or anything like that.

<sup>1 Yes, it's exactly the same word, with the same meaning, in German and English</sup>

Comment: Hi Cookie Monster. Translation is off-topic here. You can, however, reword your question such that it works as a single-word request. *Then* you can still go ahead and mention the exact equivalent in another language, but the key is that the question must still work with that bit removed.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try [German Language and Usage](http://german.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, german language and usage wouldn't help, since I am looking for an english verb with the explained denotation and connotation.

Comment: The point is, GLU is full of people who speak both languages. ELU is not. GLU handles translation questions routinely, whether from English into German or the other way round. ELU does neither. But I'm not here to coerce, just to list options.

Comment: @CookieMonster, I've edited your question so it looks more like an (allowed) single-word-request and less like a (disallowed) translation request. I know my changes look drastic, but I did try to keep all of your content (plus some information from one of your comments). However, if you feel I've butchered things, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: In my opinion one problem, that many of the authors of the answers have, is that the op is mixing metaphors:
`Sand im Getriebe` in German is a metaphor for blocking or slowing the metaphorical gears, while `versanden` is the process of slowly filling with sand, as lakes or harbours do. In the case of something getting lost I would prefer `versickern` for `seeping away`.

Comment: The same metaphor can be used with different ancilliary verbs here. "Sand im Getriebe sein" means sabotage, i.e. putting sand into some mechanics. "Sand im Getriebe haben" on the other evokes the picture of choking to me, and subsequently the administration will try to fix it. But "versanden" means the administration is not very much interested in fixing it. But yes you are right, there is a kind of clash here, since I am using the noun "Getriebe" in the sentence.

Comment: A few suggestions: http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/versandet.html

Comment: Have you tried a German-English dictionary? [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=en&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=versanden) gives some suggestions. You should also be able to start a discussion there in their forum to get more of a nuanced answer (they have a lot of good people with translation advice in both directions).

Answer (score 10):

How about "got buried" as a translation?

Comment: Maybe "got buried" is use for "versanden". But it evokes a different picture for me, more dramatic than "versanden". Like suddently an earth quake happened. But "versanden" is more like a dune moving.

Comment: Cookie Monster: funny - that's not the impression I get from the term. Still, I don't know of a better term. Sorry!

Comment: I guess the closest to "versanden" is not a dune moving, but a river slowly filling with sand. So the many requests that are not handled by the administration are the little grains of sand that slowly fill the river.

Comment: @CookieMonster: sorry, I wasn't clear. I agree with your understanding of the connotations of "versanden", but not of "get buried" (which I have also understood to be slow and incremental).

Comment: Ok. Like burried under a big staple of documents, never processed. Agreed.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. Your description of the connotations of "versanden" are the same connotations I have with "get buried" as an English speaker.

Comment: I agree with @alcas. *Got buried* is the closest match to keep the connotation in OP's example.

Answer (score 9):

Although it's not an idiom per se, describing the [*swamp*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swamp) or [*morass*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morass) of an administration creates a nice metaphor.

If you're specifically describing a sort of inefficient bureaucracy, then the phrase "[red tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_tape)" certainly applies, as well.

Comment: Can this be used as a verb, like getting red taped? What is the meaning?

Comment: Reading the red tape link, this evokes to me rather an overly precise and thus slow administration, but not a defunct administration. The red tape seems to stem from bundling a lot of documents that are needed for this precision. Reminds me of the Brazil film, especially the scene where somebody disappears in a little tornado of paper. Not sure whether this matches "versanden", since "versanden" does not imply extra precision.

Comment: @CookieMonster As a verb, you would say "caught up in red tape" or "covered in red tape". Also, I think "Brazil" is the epitome of "red tape" (great film btw). I would not put too much emphasis on the "precision" aspect, though. Looking at the Merriam-Webster definition gives better context: "official routine or procedure marked by **excessive complexity which results in delay or inaction**" (my emphasis).

Comment: I've heard the verb "mired" used in this context as well, usually with the swamp metaphor.

Comment: +1 a common idiom is *tied up in red tape*.

Answer (score 9):

As a few others have mentioned, we often use the swamp as a metaphor for bureaucracy.  (*swamp*, *bogged down*, etc.)

You might like the word *mired*.  *Mire* means a swamp, or patch of boggy ground.  If something is *mired* it is stuck in the mud.  Thus:

> The request was mired in bureaucracy.

Or, if you want to emphasise its essential bogginess:

> The request was mired in a fetid morass of red tape.

(*red tape* means *troublesome, excessive bureaucratic procedures*)

Comment: I like mired.  But fetid means (re)productive and doesn't belong in the same sentence as bureaucracy.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: No, it's derived from Latin `fetidus` ("stinking"). See also `f(o)etor` as in `foetor ex ore` ("bad breath").

Answer (score 9):

> Caught up in red tape

is certainly idiomatic but relates more to delays rather than total losses.
To imply that something never makes it out of administation due to excessive bureaucracy and regulations you could say

> it got buried under a mountain of red tape

Comment: 'The request was drowned in red tape' also common

Comment: "tangled in red tape" is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 4):

If you're of a literary inclination and the audience is suitably well-read, I think this might be a good excuse to use the word *Kafkaesque*, e.g.

> The request disappeared into a Kafkaesque nightmare.

There's also an obvious Orwellian alternative:

> The request vanished down a memory hole.

Answer (score 3):

Google Translate suggests

> The request is bogged down in the gears of bureaucracy

but using *gears* isn't very idiomatic. How about

> The request is lost in their bureaucratic machinery
>   The request has been swallowed by their bureaucracy

or something else using *bogged down*, or even *buried* [as Billy suggests](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/81208/18696)? (I upvoted that; *buried* is idiomatic.)

Comment: Bogged down sounds to me as if the request was complicated or so, and was therefore refused. But idea is that it is a simple request, and that all these simple request have the faith of getting lost, since the administration is not functioning.

Comment: No, *bogged down* means stuck in a bog; progress is difficult if you are continually sucked in.

Comment: Oki Doki. Sounds good.

Comment: *Swallowed* is actually quite good. It has the connotation that the administration is no longer under the perfect control of the people in it, and it has become a creature of its own with its own unpredictable, incorrect behaviour, such as eating requests.

Comment: I don't think something can get "bogged down in the gears" - sounds like a mixed metaphor.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Yes. That's why I said where it came from and that it wasn't very idiomatic. It's rather a good mixed metaphor, but it's not something I would recommend (and I haven't).

Answer (score 2):

To capture all the elements of the original German, I think you need something like:

> lost in the quicksand of a dysfunctional bureaucracy

which is not (AFAIK) an established idiom, but should be comprehensible to most English speakers.

Quicksand is a rather elegant word which has its roots in a Middle-English word for "living", "quyk", which still survives in its old meaning of "lively" or "living", rather than just meaning "rapid", in one or two corners of modern English, like "quicksand" and "cut to the quick" (cut to the living tissue)

Alternately:

> lost in the **shifting sands** of a dysfunctional bureaucracy

"shifting sands" is a known idiomatic phrase, and I think captures something of the essence of "versandet"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact problem , you might be *[getting the run-around](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/run+around)*...

> *Informal* deceitful or evasive treatment of a person (esp in the
>   phrase **give** or **get the run-around**)

This usually applies to the situation where one is continually referred from department to department by people whose objective is to get rid of you rather than solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think all OP needs to do is change the ancillary verb...

> *The request **was** lost in the bowels of the administration.*

Using *"got"* casts "the request" as an "active agent", that *lost its way, got **itself** lost*. Using *"was"* implies that *something else* (the bureaucracy) failed to track and process the request. In support of that *got/was* distinction, consider...

> "I got/was comfortable" *("**got**" implies **I did something** to become comfortable)*.
>
> "I got/was shaved this morning" *("**got**" implies *"I shaved **myself**", where "**was**" implies "**someone else** shaved me")*.

I think that small change is in the spirit of [typical British understatement](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22round%20ball%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22british%20understatement%22&oq=%22british%20understatement%22&gs_l=serp.3...7146.7835.3.8187.5.5.0.0.0.0.57.260.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.3Cpy3UjqIkc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=56b4fc6f2aa799ce&biw=1379&bih=886), and is quite enough to imply that the bureaucracy was *actively at fault*, rather than that the request  unexpectedly and atypically happened to run into some  *"bad luck"*.

Answer (score 1):

> The request got lost in bureaucratic sand

would be lovely (it's a great idiom even with sand as a noun).  It's not a common idiom at all, but I think it's still clear as a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

At Zoot's urging, I offer the amusing idiom *[fall between the cracks](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/11/fall-between-the-cracks/)*, or alternately the more-easily-understood *[fall through the cracks](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+through+the+cracks)*.  The meanings of the two phrases are about the same: “to get lost or be forgotten, especially within a system [*eg*] It seems that important information given to the police may have fallen through the cracks.”  These idioms are slightly contrary to *versandet* in that they suggest dust or sand filtering away through holes in the system, rather than infiltrating into the gears and workings of a system.

Some other terms to consider: *[dustbin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dustbin#English)* (“bin for holding rubbish until it can be collected; a garbage can”) or  *[dustheap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dustheap)* (“a pile of refuse” or “a category of forgotten items [*eg*] the dustheap of history — New Republic”) may be used as in “Their case fell into the bureaucratic dustbin” or “Their plea lay lost upon the bureaucratic dust heap”.  Also *[sweep under the rug/carpet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweep+under+the+rug)* (“to conceal something in the hopes it won't be discovered by others; [*eg*] "The president tried to sweep the embarrassing incident under the rug"”)  may be used as in “The bureaucrats swept all the information under the bureaucratic rug”.  Verb *[fritter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fritter#Verb)* (“To occupy oneself idly or without clear purpose, to tinker with an unimportant part of a project, to dally, sometimes as a form of procrastination”) may apply: “The end-of-September deadline arrived before the purchasing department left off frittering with the proposal.”

Answer (score 0):

While I think the equivalent English idiom is the metaphor of the swamp, with Pitarou's "mired" working equally well in the mixed metaphor "mired in the bowels of the bureaucracy", you may be able to retain part of the German idiom by transforming it into something like:

```
The request is adrift in the sand dunes of the bureaucracy.
```

or:

```
The request has gone adrift in the sand dunes of the bureaucracy.
```

I can't think of a way of retaining both "sand" and "bowels" without resorting to a poetic style that isn't present in the original. At best, You'd end up with something like "the request is adrift in the bowels of the bureaucracy", and adrift by itself will imply a in naval context rather than a desert one.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that "versanden" is the short form of "im Sande verlaufen". Which would be translated into "to run off into sand".

http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewWrongentry.php?idThread=670006

Or maybe translated into "fizzle out".

http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=im%20Sande%20Sand%20verlaufen&in=&kbd=de&l=deen

But I am not sure how to form the whole sentence then.

Comment: *Im Sande verlaufen* means to fail. *Versanden*, on the contrary, means *to stop*. Your use of *versanden* is figuratively regarding the "main definition" *to fill with sand* where your sand is the mass of other stuff. Thus, neither *to run off into sand* nor *to fizzle out* would fit in your context.

Comment: There is also "in den Sand setzten". This is typically used for projects that fail, emphasizing the loss. But it is not exactly the same as "im Sande verlaufen", which means gradually stop and/or fail I guess. Meanwhile I found an example sentence with "fizzle out" that matches "versanden": here: http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/versandet.html

Comment: These linguee translation are really not good. The *fizzle out* example on that page has a completely different meaning to the one you introduced in your question. I wouldn't recommend you to use *fizzle out* here.

Comment: I find (via the idioms.thefreedictionary.com): Fig. to fade or become ineffectual gradually, and Fig. [for an item in a fireworks display] to fail to operate properly, often producing only a hiss. Why do you think this doesn't match? This looks extremely close to me. P.S. English has a very large vocabulary, so its very natural for me that there are many matches.

Comment: "fizzle out" means probably "verpufft" in German, which uses another metaphor than sand I agree.

Comment: Yep. *verpufft* for *fizzle out* would fit in some contexts. However, *versanden* doesn't mean neither that something becomes ineffectual nor to fail. *Versanden*, as you said in your Q, means to get lost but will likely be done successfully at a later date (when it came up again for any reason)

Comment: No, "versandet" means it will not be done at a later date. It means that it was not done, in all contexts I have found it so far. Exept if you revive it from outside, but per se it means the request was not handled, and will also not come up again from the inside for any reason. defunct = not working.

Comment: Well, yeah. You're right. I just thought of a conversation like: "What has happened to X? - It has been forgotten (versandet) - Well, will you do it now?" That's the moment where it's reviving. - On the contrary *im Sande verläuft* has a more ... abgeschlossen ... connotation. You're done with it and you have no interest in reviving it. And the second difference I see: *Im sande verlaufen* means it has been weakened gradually (e.g. mail conversation to a person you know from holiday), while *versanden* is more "suddenly". You just haven't thought of it any more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native dutch speaker and we have the same word, verzanden.

The best english equivalent with that meaning is **stranded**.

Swamped kinda gives an overwhelmed sense, bogged down is that it encountered difficulties

- German: Die Anfrage ist im Gebtriebe der Bürokratie versandet.
- Dutch : De aanvraag is in de bureaucratische molen verzand,
- English: The request has stranded in the workings of bureaucracy

---

- **strand** 1  (strnd) n. The land bordering a body of water; a beach. v.
  **strand·ed**, **strand·ing**, **strands** v.tr.

  1. To drive or run ashore or aground.
  2. To bring into or leave in a difficult or helpless position: The convoy was stranded in the desert.
  3. Baseball To leave (a base runner) on base at the end of an inning.
  4. Linguistics To separate (a grammatical element) from other elements in a construction, either by moving it out of the
     construction or moving the rest of the construction. In the sentence
     What are you aiming at, the preposition at has been stranded.
     v.intr.
  5. To be driven or run ashore or aground.
  6. To be brought into or left in a difficult or helpless position.

Comment: *Strand* is a transitive verb; in your 'English' bullet it needs to cast in the passive voice.

Answer (score 0):

I propose

[lost in the shuffle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+in+the+shuffle)

[The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

The commonest collocation for the case of something's being lost without trace is **"Lost in the mists of time"** but the two noun can be varied as is shown in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20mists%20of%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cin%20the%20mists%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20antiquity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20history%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20fable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20ignorance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20obscurity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mists%20of%20error%3B%2Cc0) Thus we would have:

**"Lost in the mists of bureaucracy"**

Or more graphically,

**"Lost in the swamps/jungle of bureaucracy."**